# VARIANT pointer gets corrupted when passed as function parameter to different assembly (C++ DLL)

Tags: c#, c++, dll, variant

i am not quite sure how to explain my issue here but will try best to make you understand.

There are 2 scenario,

1. C# Application --> CPPDLL1 -> CPPDLL2 -> CPPDLL3.
2. VB6 Application --> CPPDLL1 -> CPPDLL2 -> CPPDLL3.

Scenario 1:

There is a c# application which Loads a c++ dll(CPPDLL1) which in turn loads another c++ dll(CPPDLL2) which in turn loads one more c++ dll(CPPDLL3).

Here a SafeArray is created in "CPPDLL2" and is passed as function parameter in the form of "VARIANT Pointer" to a function defined and exposed in "CPPDLL3"

The ISSUE here is this variant ptr gets corrupted when the execution reach from function call to definition.

Scenario 2:

Same as Scenario 1 except VB6 application in the place of C# application.
All is well, No Issues observed.

---

Pseudo code:

**CPPDLL2.cpp**

```
VARIANT OutPara;
SAFEARRAYBOUND saOutPara[]={1,0};

VariantInit(&OutPara);

OutPara.parray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_R8,1,saOutPara); 
CoCreateInstance();

FunctionDefinedInCPPDLL3(VARIANT *varInstance);
```

**CPPDLL3.cpp**

```
FunctionDefinedInCPPDLL3(VARIANT *varInstance)
{
//varInstance is corrupted
//Do your job;
}
```

Any clues about the solution or suggestions are appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Well, here's one suggestion: take a [tour] of stackoverflow.com, visit the [help], and read the instructions for preparing a [mcve]. There's an obvious bug in the code, somewhere, but without a [mcve] it is logically impossible for anyone to find it, anyone other than you, of course, since only you would have access to all the code.

Comment: A SafeArray is a structure.  So you need to pass the structure.  The best way to understand this is look at the c++ code (and link at beginning) at following msdn webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt778923.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the reply, just to add one more thing, if i have 2 variant pointer parameters in the function, the first parameter is fine, the second one is corrupted. Also everything works just fine in case the base application is of VB6.